# Is there any MathParser that parse a mathematical string expression containing average function like avg(value1 + value2 + value3) + ...?

Tags: winforms, math, c#-4.0

I have a text box and I simply type a mathematical expression like:

```
sin(1) + 2 + cos(5) + sqrt(5)
```

and pass it to my MathParser class object and it returns me the result.

I went through the class and found that for mathematical operators like +, -, *, /; there is a function which returns 2 because these operations can be performed only between two parameters like '1 + 2' and mathematical functions like sin, cos, tan, abs, sqrt; have a single parameter like sin(param), etc. so it returns 1.

Now, I want to add average function also, but problem is that when I type the expression avg(1+2+3+4), it gives priority to bracket first and add all the numbers, that's fine but for average I need the number of arguments passes within that function. I somehow managed to count for first average but what if it occurs with other functions or it occurs more than one time?

Is there any mathParser available which can have an avg built in function? I don't see it in Visual Studio Math class also.

Comment: The average is a function for lists of numbers, the syntax should be `avg(1,2,3,4)` or `avg([1,2,3,4])` (vararg argument or list object argument) or similar.

Comment: If I'm following you well, your problem can be solved with a [parameter array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx). If the purpose of your function is to get the average of a list of numbers, you should be passing as a parameter such list of numbers, not the sum of them.

Comment: Here's an open source math parser that supports user defined functions, but it's in `Java`, so you would have to port it to `C#`: http://sourceforge.net/projects/expression-tree/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an open-source math parser supporting variadic functions (including average), which I was recently using in my project. The parser name is mXparser. Parser is implemented in C# and separately in JAVA.

https://mxparser.codeplex.com/

http://mathparser.org/

Your problem can be simply solved, please follow the below example

Simple average including variadic parameters

```
Expression e = new Expression("avg(2, 5, 6, 34, 2, 10) + avg(5, 4, 32)");
double v = e.calculate()
```

Simple average including variables in variadic parameters

```
Argument x = new Argument("x = 5");
Expression e = new Expression("avg(2, 5, 2*x, 34, 2, 10) + avg(5, 4*x, 32)", x);
double v = e.calculate()
```

Average as iterated operator

```
Expression e = new Expression("avg(i, 1, 100, i^2);
double v = e.calculate()
```

Best regards